# Issue when clicking checkbox label

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

Whenever I click on the label (in a checkbox), it goes to the top of the page.

I have actually deleted all scripts and style, and still gives the same result. It's probably related to the loop, but still investigating.

```
<% @requests.each do |request| %>
    <%= form_with(model: request, remote: true, :id => "form#{id}", :class => "form-class") do |form| %>
        <%= form.collection_check_boxes :category_ids, Category.all, :id, :name do |b| %>    
          <%= b.check_box %>
          <%= b.label   %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The generated HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" value="24" name="request[category_ids][]" id="request_category_ids_24">
<label for="request_category_ids_24">This is a general option</label>
```

Each label and input have unique ids

It should selected the checkbox, and do nothing, but instead goes to the top of the page.

Comment: Perhaps show a [mcve] using HTML and jQuery?

Comment: As this is a HTML problem you would get more accurate answers more quickly if you show the actual HTML output instead of the Ruby logic

Comment: I'm thinking. This actually never happens in html, and I'm just using Ruby logic in my code. I'm doing some investigations thought. Thank you for your kind attention.

Comment: The Ruby logic is outputting HTML. It may well be caused by any additional JS you have, though. Look for a `for` attribute on the the `label` HTML output

Comment: You are right, I'm updating my question.

Comment: 1: You have an event listener that submits an empty form OR 2: you have a link that reloads the page with a missing </a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when you create a loop of Forms in rails, it will eventually create non-unique IDs between inputs and labels and different parts of the loop. It has to do with the connection between the "for" of the label and the "id" of input.

In order to fix that, create custom IDs to make sure the label activate the right checkbox.

Problem:

```
<%= b.check_box %>
<%= b.label   %>
```

Solution:

```
<%= b.check_box id: "#{request.id}-#{b.value}" %>
<%= b.label for: "#{request.id}-#{b.value}" %>
```